Characteristics Equation for Exponential Power Distribution (zero mean)
I am trying to find the characteristic equation for the Exponential Power Distribution (otherwise known as Generalized Normal Distribution).
I want to get this so that I can check if $X \sim \text{ExpPow}(\kappa, 0, \sigma)$ what the distribution of $Y = \sum^n_{i = 1} X_i^2$ is. Assume n IID $X_i$.

Welcome to MSE, DysonSphere! What is your progress so far? What have you tried? Please, avoid no-clue questions
